# Increase upload speed by repeating the same packets in networks with many users

Tags: upload, qos

Assume I am just a user and I'm optimizing for my upload packets, not the throughput for everyone.

Say the network you're in is limited in bandwidth because there are too many users. Would it be effective to code a proxy that sends every outgoing packets multiple times, to increase upload speed? As far as I'm aware [TCP allows receiving packets multiple times](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DuplicatePackets). It seems that Random Early Detection and similar algorithms are run after all packets are pooled (or not?), so router wouldn't know that those packets come from the same user while doing QoS, or QoS might be wrongly configured by default.

The goal is to add redundancy to my packets, so instead of the router dropping my single packets, I'm sending each of my packets twice. While the packet drop rate increases, it's very unlikely that one pair of same packets is removed.

Here's an example of what I mean:

There are 110 packets per second in a network, 10 of which are mine. The router can send only 100 packets. So 10/110 * 100% = 9% of all packets will be dropped. Average value of my packets dropped per second is 10*0.09 = 0.9.

But if I send 20 packets per second, then 20/120*100% = 17% of all packets will be dropped. 20*0.17 = 3.4 of my packets will be dropped. But every packet is sent twice, 
so we can assume on average 1.7 will be dropped from the first batch and 1.7 will be dropped from the second batch. It's very likely that those 3.4 packets out of each 20 packets will be different, so all my packets would reach their destination.

[image]

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your situation, but if you're using a webserver, (pre)compression might save you a lot of bandwidth (and possibly CPU cycles)

Comment: Why do you think this would _increase_ upload speed?

Comment: Because my repeated packets would make larger proportion of all outgoing packets in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

If your uplink is congested, then putting more strain on it via packet multiplication will slow your upload speed.

The point is, that all the infrastucture in the path will try for your repeat packets (which you don't need to really arrive) exactly as hard as for the first copy, so while the proportion of your packet on the link is higher, the proportion of your **actually neeed** packets is lower.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to magically increase throughput by sending more data. That would be a perpetual motion machine.

Since you mention setting up a proxy, what you CAN do is compress the data. If the data you are sending/receiving is compressible, you can set up a VPN or a PPP tunnel and enable compression. OpenVPN, pppd and various other tools you could use for this support various different compression modes. If your proxy has more bandwidth than your local end point, this will improve your throughput, but the effectiveness will largely depend on how compressible the data is. If most of your bandwidth is already consumed by data that is compressed (e.g. streaming media), you probably won't gain enough from this to make the exercise worthwhile.